# Terraform azurerm provider incompatible for Mac M1

Tags: apple-m1, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

Terraform provider for Azure in Mac is problematic so i installed using the workaround mentioned here [m1-terraform-provider-helper](https://github.com/kreuzwerker/m1-terraform-provider-helper).

After reinstalling terraform as below the provider for Azurerm is still not compatable for Mac arm devices.

```bash
# Removed any existing Terraform binary (/usr/bin/terraform and/or /usr/local/bin/terraform)
# Install m1-terraform-provider-helper

brew install kreuzwerker/taps/m1-terraform-provider-helper

# Install Terraform
brew tap hashicorp/tap

brew install hashicorp/tap/terraform

# Install the hashicorp/template version v2.2.0
m1-terraform-provider-helper install hashicorp/template -v v2.2.0
```

```bash
terraform init
```

```bash
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "2.46.0"...
╷
│ Error: Incompatible provider version
│
│ Provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.46.0 does not have a package available for your current platform, darwin_arm64.
```

How do i go about fixing this? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Using the latest azurerm provider `version = "=3.0.1"` fixes this. Here is the config.

```bash
terraform {
    
    required_providers {
    azurerm = {
        source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
        version = "=3.0.1"
    }
    }
}
```